# Отправка двух Ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

Необходимо отправить Ajax запрос и в случае успеха отправить второй с данными из первого.
Я пробовал вот так но ошибки и результат не выводит.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.save').click(function call() {
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://site.ru/index.php?text='+text,
        success: function(jsondata){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'http://site.ru/secondary.php?id='+jsondata.id,
                success: function(jsondata){
                    $('.results').html(jsondata.stdout);
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: А второй путь сформулирован правильно? 'http://site.ru/secondary.php'+jsondata.id попробуйте его вывести при помощи console.log, там ничего подозрительного нет, например, пропущенный символ знака вопроса?

Comment: Это когда я сюда писал ошибся.
Код правил.

Comment: Я бы натыкал везде console.log, чтобы понять где затык, выведите console.log jsondata в обеих функциях - хотя бы один набор данных приходит?

Comment: С первого запроса идут данные, а вот на второй запрос идет но данные не возвращает. @cheops

Comment: Помимо success, обработайте еще error - посмотрите что там приходит

Comment: $("#text").val() parseFloat или parseInteger имхо. Не jsondata.id, а скорее jsondata.responseText.id Имхо сразу после строки succes затычку консоль.лог(jsondata)

Comment: и где ваш дом.риди?

Comment: Данные передаются и запросы и ответы есть оба, но jsondata.stdout просто не отображается  хотя запрос отправлен и ответ получен.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте промисы, а именно [чейнинг](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2). Это идеальное решение для Вашего случая.

```
    // сделать запрос
$.get('https://learn.javascript.ru/article/promise/user.json')
  // 1. Получить данные о пользователе в JSON и передать дальше
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    let user = JSON.parse(response);
    return user;
  })
  // 2. Получить информацию с github
  .then(user => {
    console.log(user);
    return httpGet(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`);
  })
  // 3. Вывести аватар на 3 секунды (можно с анимацией)
  .then(githubUser => {
    console.log(githubUser);
    githubUser = JSON.parse(githubUser);

    let img = new Image();
    img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
    img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
    document.body.appendChild(img);

    setTimeout(() => img.remove(), 3000); // (*)
  });
```

**При чейнинге, то есть последовательных вызовах .then…then…then, в каждый следующий then переходит результат от предыдущего.**

Comment: Все правильно и грамотно.

Comment: подход с коллбэками в вопросе будет работать абсолютно так же, чем тут может помочь использование `then`?